# Submit a Form with HTML within PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Why does that not submit my form?
I tested it with sending an E-Mail to me just before the Javascript part. I receive it but the Javascript part is not working. I also did a console.log, nothing happened..

I am using `jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js`

The `$data` Array is filled with strings.
For example: `$data['key1'] = 'test1';`

```
echo "<form action='http://example.com' method='POST' id='my-form'>";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        hidden_field($key, $value, array('id' => null));
    }         
echo '</form>';
# DEBUG
sendmail('my@email.com', "SUBMIT NOW", 'SUBMITTED NOW', null, false, $order['email'], $order['name']);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#my-form").submit();</script>';
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?Have you tried wrapping your jQuery in a document ready handler?

Comment: @Alf — No. The `<script>` appears after the `<form>`.

Comment: also call submit when document is ready

Comment: I just tried `$( document ).ready(function() { $("#my-form").submit(); });` no change..

Answer (score 8):

You don't have a `<my-form>` element in your HTML.

An id selector needs to begin with a `#` character.

```
$("#my-form").submit();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong in the Javascript.

```
$("my-form").submit();
```

Should be

```
$("#my-form").submit();
```

Try also wrapping it like this so that you know that everything is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-form").submit();
});
```

Comment: @Vince Are you getting any javascript errors? What happens if you put an alert before the submit?

Comment: The chrome developer tools is not showing any error. I already tried it with `console.log`, which has the same effect for testing ;)

Comment: @Vince stupid question but did you remember to include jquery? Lets see the HTML that your script outputs.

Comment: Actually, the file is accessed in the background (it's a framework). So you don't see the form. But jquery is included. I checked it with developer tools -> Resources -> site.php -> jquery.js

Answer (score 3):

Add `#` to identify its id

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#my-form").submit();</script>';
```

if your using javascript try this -

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
         document.getElementById('my-form').submit();
     </script>";
```

Comment: try this if your using javascript - `document.getElementById('my-form').submit();`

Comment: I just tried it. Please note, that even `console.log("...");` isn't working.

Comment: now remove or comment the script and view the source code of your form, it's may be issue with form input data.

Comment: Which part should I comment? The loop?